# Cannot create database when running docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When running **docker-compose up -d**, I expect 2 databases to be created.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

volumes:
  db_data:

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Password123
      - POSTGRES_DB=database1
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  platform:
    image: image1/platform:${TAG:-latest}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: PlatformApi/Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Local
      - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Server=postgres;Port=5432;Uid=postgres;Pwd=Password123;Database=database1
    ports:
      - "5001:80"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .docker/setup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup.sql
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql

  identity:
    image: image2/identity:${TAG:-latest}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Identity/Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Local
      - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Server=postgres;Port=5432;Uid=postgres;Pwd=Password123;Database=database2
    ports:
      - "5002:80"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .docker/setup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup.sql
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
```

This is my **setup.sql** file which is located inside a `.docker` folder

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS database1;

CREATE USER postgres IDENTIFIED BY Password123;
GRANT CREATE, ALTER, INDEX, LOCK TABLES, REFERENCES, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, SELECT, INSERT ON database1.* TO postgres;

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS database2;

CREATE USER postgres IDENTIFIED BY Password123;
GRANT CREATE, ALTER, INDEX, LOCK TABLES, REFERENCES, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, SELECT, INSERT ON database2.* TO postgres;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

When I run **docker-compose up -d**, 3 containers are created but 1 of them is exited with an error `database "database2" does not exist`.

What did I do wrong? Did the **setup.sql** file not execute or is the content incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the postgres service you initiate the Database with the following config

```
  postgres:
    image: postgres:alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Password123
      - POSTGRES_DB=database1
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

As a result a database with name `database1` is created

In the following services you try to firstly connect to the database

---

In platform service:

```
  - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=...;Database=database1
```

Here there is no issue since `database1` exists

---

But in `identity` service:

```
- ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=...;Database=database2
```

You try to connect to `database2` which `does not exist`

---

The reason it does not exist is that there are `race conditions` in your `setup.sql`. You can not guarantee that when the `identity` service initiates, that the `database2` would be already created by `platform` service.

---

To tackle this, you could add `postgres2` service which creates the `database2`

```
  postgres2:
    image: postgres:alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Password123
      - POSTGRES_DB=database2
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"

  identity:
    image: image2/identity:${TAG:-latest}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Identity/Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Local
      - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Server=postgres2;Port=5432;Uid=postgres;Pwd=Password123;Database=database2
    ports:
      - "5002:80"
    depends_on:
      - postgres2
    volumes:
      - .docker/setup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup.sql
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
```